# Show $X_n \to 0$ in probability

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, convergence, measure-theory

I am asked to show :

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable on $(\Omega, F , P)$ and define

$X_n(\omega) = nX(\omega)$ if $n<X(\omega)\le n+1$ and $0$ if else. Prove that $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

Comment: (+1) Welcome to Stats.SE. You might be interested to know that you can use math typesetting via Mathjax. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Are you sure you stated the problem as intended?  By writing "$(\Omega,F,P),$" you suggest $\Omega$ is an abstract set, but in writing "if $n\lt w\le n+1$" you imply the positive real numbers are in $\Omega.$

Comment: X is a real valued RV. The question might not be perfectly written but I took it as it is

Comment: That's not the issue: the issue is that the *argument* of $X,$ which you call "w," must be a real value for this problem statement to make sense. At the very least, your book/exam/professor is making assumptions or restrictions that you haven't put in evidence here.

Comment: oh yes I see your point. But if you skip the fact that small omega is in R, I still can't see how I should proceed. To be more precise, the RV is written using an indicator function and not an if statement, but that wouldn't change much ( as in it's equal to n*1(n;n+1)*X(w))

Comment: I don't see any use of indicator functions in your question.  You might benefit from drawing graphs of some of the $X_n$ and contemplating what happens to the chances that their values exceed zero. What I wonder is whether the clause "$n\lt w\le n+1$" should instead read "$n\lt X(w)\le n+1.$" That would make sense for any abstract probability space; it would imply the same conclusion; but would require a different solution.

Comment: You are right I checked a different version (last year's paper) , and the one I was looking at was wrong. It is indeed <()≤+1. Now Xn(w) is equal to n if <()≤+1 and 0 else.

Comment: Please, then, edit your post to reflect that and add the [tag:self-study] tag after [reading information about it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to show that $X_n(\omega)\stackrel{as}{\to}0$ and note that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.

$X_n(\omega)=0$ for all $n>X(\omega)$, so for every fixed $\omega$, $X_n(\omega)\to 0$.

Therefore $X_n(\omega)\stackrel{as}{\to}0$, and it is a standard fact that this implies $X_n(\omega)\stackrel{p}{\to}0$